# jQuery/JavaScript: keep JSON object with latest date grouped by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object as below. There are about 100 objects in `GpResultsCollection` in total.

```
{
    "GpResultsCollection": [
        {
            "Date": "2021-01-14T00:00:00", // BRING BACK LATEST
            "Rubric": "Pivmecillinam 200mg tablets", // DUPLICATES BASED ON THIS
            "ReadCode": "PITA2286",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Dosage": "two tablets for first dose, the one tablet every 8 hours until completed course (of ten tablets)",
            "Units": "tablet",
            "TenancyDescription": "Orglinks"
        },
        {
            "Date": "2021-01-07T00:00:00", // BRING BACK LATEST
            "Rubric": "Pivmecillinam 200mg tablets", // DUPLICATES BASED ON THIS
            "ReadCode": "COCO138186NEMIS",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Dosage": "1 dose by Intramuscular Injection",
            "Units": "dose",
            "TenancyDescription": "Orglinks"
        }
...
```

What I want is the same object but with duplicates excluded based on the `Date`. So in the above example, it would keep the first one and remove the second one

I have jQuery/JavaScript available.

Any suggestions? I've tried looping through and keeping a record of what's been passed already but now back at a a blank screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const orginal = []; // assume that this variable contains the array
const filtered = [];

function filteredContainsDate(date) {
    return filtered.filter(element => element.Date == date).length > 0;
}

original.forEach(function (element)  {
    if (!filteredContainsDate(element.Date))
        filtered.push(element);
});
```

This code would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by `Date` and then take the first unique by `Rubric`.

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) it's super simple: [(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/qgmynte9/)

```js
let uniqueArray = _.sortBy(GpResultsCollection, '-Date');

uniqueArray = _.uniqBy(uniqueArray, 'Rubric');
```